# Angular 2.0 - Get directive's model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can get the model that has been bound to an input element in a directive?

`<input [(ng-model)]="user.firstname">`

How I can access to `user` model to modify its `firstname` prop? In my case I don't want to modify `value` prop of the input directly instead I want to modify its model.
My temporary solution is sending `user` and `firstname` as input parameters to the directive.

`<input [model]="user" [prop]="'firstname'" [(ng-model)]="user.firstname">`

What is the correct way?

Comment: I want to create a directive for currency mask